# Can't take more than 30 entries from atom feed (GitHub private feed)

Tags: c#, github, rss, github-api

I am taking atom feed with this code:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

            var feed = await client.GetStringAsync(_session.GetPrivateFeedUrl());

            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(feed) ) return new List<XElement>();

            var parsedFeed = XElement.Parse(feed);

            var entries = from entry in parsedFeed.Elements("{" + ConstantsService.AtomNamespace + "}entry") select entry;

            return entries;
```

But this takes only 30 entries (reads). And I think it is because if you open private feed token url, that you will see only 30 elements of feed. And if you go on https://github.com/ , it is still 30, but there you can press "More" button, but you can't do this with page from url. How to take more than 30 elements (all) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to RSS feeds, but the API has pagination https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: I knew about pagination, but couldn't figure out how to add it to URL, that Github API gives. After I saw your comment, I started to search one more time and found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't find the answer how to get more than 30 items, but I figured out how to read from another page, where you have another 30 items, and so on.
After your private feed URL, you should add this:
 `&page=2` 
In this case, you will read the second page. If you don't  add a page, it reads the first page.
If someone will find way to get more than 30 items from page, please share it.